# Datepicker jQuery UI does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am try to use datepicker from jQuery UI, but it is not work and this is my code. What should I add to make it work?

```
<html lang="us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
        <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the element with id datepicker? Refer this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/387/

Comment: Where is the `</head>` and `<body>`?

Comment: thank you for your note for Head and body

Comment: Make sure the libraries are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need an input field where the date picker can store the selected value.
The #datepicker in your js defines that the datepicker library looks for an element with the id datepicker (see the input field below):

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Example Page</title>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Since you seem to have some further issues, does this version work for you?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi you are right I am missing the text, but I am try to run your code but it is not working also

Comment: I've added a version with external links to the js libraries, give that a try.

Comment: Well, if I copy the above into jsFiddle it works just fine. Sorry, but I can't help you further than that. I assume the following works for you as well? http://jsfiddle.net/e8L53w1r/

Comment: actually if you try to save this page in you computer it will not work , but online it will work , I don't know what is the reason online work offline not work [link]http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html[link]